# Trying to boot to USB stick

Tags: dual-boot, usb

I have gone through the intial steps and downloaded the files to a USB drive.  I have setup my computer to boot to USB.  When I try to do install and run the file I'm using the Boot from CD.  I restart and it's still not trying to boot to the drive.

I've even tried to just unpack and install to the stick, but it says it doesn't have enough space.  The stick is a 64 GB stick.

Comment: You should donwload the ISO file and use the programs mentioned in the documentation to properly create the bootable live USB. just copying the ISO or unpacking it in the USB will not work.

Comment: It sounds as if you're downloading the .iso and copying it to the USB drive. If so, that's never gonna work. An .iso file is an image, a kind of archive file containing all the information needed to recreate multiple files and sub-files, the entire directory structure of a hard disk, a CD, a DVD, or a USB drive. You need to use the appropriate software to copy the original directory structure that's rolled up and hidden inside that .iso file onto your USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

To boot from a CD or USB drive:
Plug in the usb.

Restart your computer and wait for that first screen to pop up.

Often, it'll say something like "Press F12 to Choose Boot Device" somewhere on the screen. ...

Give it a moment to continue booting, and you should see a menu pop up with a list of 
choices on it.

Select the usb that you installed the .iso file on . It should then begin booting up!

Thanks, hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To install Ubuntu from USB stick, try using [LiLi](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/), it's easy tool to install Live installer on USB key from .ISO file. Then:

- boot your PC, open BIOS control center, and change boot order so USB is first OR
- open boot menu (Typically F12, check google for kay matching your board) and select USB device. Then rest is just pressing enter as you install Ubuntu

Comment: I went through the steps on the main page.  I downloaded the .iso file.  Went through the launcher and selected the .iso.  It seems to have created the image.  In the BIOS I have selected USB to the primary boot.  When the computer starts coming up it reads the drive, but then never boots. The program I used was pendrivelinux.com